# Permutations for Brute Force

Tags: java, permutation, brute-force

I am trying to get some permutations which I will later use to brute force an adjacency matrix. The code below may not be efficient but it works. I want to add all the outputted permutations into an array. I am struggling to do this. Can anyone help?

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter num: ");
    int num = in.nextInt();

    String str = "";
    for (int i=0; i < num; i++){
      String temp = Integer.toString(i); 
      str += temp;
    }

    int n = str.length(); 
    Permutation permutation = new Permutation(); 
    permutation.permute(str, 0, n-1);

  }
}


class Permutation { 
  public void permute(String str, int l, int r){ 
    if (l == r) {
      System.out.println(str);
    }
    else{ 
      for (int i = l; i <= r; i++){ 
        str = swap(str,l,i); 
        permute(str, l+1, r); 
        str = swap(str,l,i); 
      } 
    }

  } 

  public String swap(String a, int i, int j) { 
    char temp; 
        char[] charArray = a.toCharArray(); 
        temp = charArray[i] ; 
        charArray[i] = charArray[j]; 
        charArray[j] = temp; 
        String perm = String.valueOf(charArray);
    return perm;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Well, instead of printing the permutation add it to the array ...

Comment: Yes I have tried that but I get it wrong everytime. Where would I append?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just instead of printing, store them in a list. Here I have used a `LinkedList`.

```
class Permutation { 

    static LinkedList<String> output= new LinkedList<>(); //<---for storing result 

  public void permute(String str, int l, int r){ 
    if (l == r) {
    //   System.out.println(str);

        output.addLast(str); //<----store it in the linkedlist
    }
    else{ 
      for (int i = l; i <= r; i++){ 
        str = swap(str,l,i); 
        permute(str, l+1, r); 
        str = swap(str,l,i); 
      } 
    }

  }
```

After that, you can print the result from Main.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    .....

    code
    ....

    permutation.permute(str, 0, n-1);
    System.out.println(Permutation.output); //<----print the result
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. That worked as intended. Thx for the quick response. :)

Comment: I had kept trying to return an array from that function which hadnt worked XD

Comment: @Student01 well in that case you had to declare the list inside the Main and also pass the reference of that list

Comment: @Student01  Please close the question, if you don't have any more issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter num: ");
    int num = in.nextInt();

    String str = "";
    for (int i=0; i < num; i++){
      String temp = Integer.toString(i); 
      str += temp;
    }

    int n = str.length(); 
    Permutation permutation = new Permutation(); 
    List<String> permutations = permutation.allPermutations(str, 0, n-1);
  }
}


class Permutation {
  List<String> permutations;

  public List<String> allPermutations(String str, int l, int r){ 
    permutations = new ArrayList<String();
    permute(str, l, r);

    return permutations;
  }

  public void permute(String str, int l, int r){ 
    if (l == r) {
      // System.out.println(str);
      permutations.add(str);
    }
    else{ 
      for (int i = l; i <= r; i++){ 
        str = swap(str,l,i); 
        permute(str, l+1, r); 
        str = swap(str,l,i); 
      } 
    }

  } 

  public String swap(String a, int i, int j) { 
    char temp; 
        char[] charArray = a.toCharArray(); 
        temp = charArray[i] ; 
        charArray[i] = charArray[j]; 
        charArray[j] = temp; 
        String perm = String.valueOf(charArray);
    return perm;
  } 
}
```